# MacBook Pro Fans take 1 minute to stop making noise after getting in sleep mode

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, display, sleep-wake

When put in sleep mode,it takes exactly one minute, so 60 seconds, for the fans to stop making noise, even when closing the lid.

Also, when awaken from sleep, clicking on the sleep button in the apple menu does nothing until at least 30 to 60 seconds have elapsed. So if the mac is waken up from  sleep, I need to wait at least 30 to 60 seconds before the sleep button in the apple menu puts the mac to sleep again.

Is this normal ?

It's a MacBook Pro Unibody 15'' mid 2012. The battery got swollen a year ago, and I needed to replace both the battery and the keyboard because some parts of the keyboard were damaged by the swollen battery and became unresponsive. The first replacement cable I got was defectuous, the secondly was accidentaly damaged by me, and the third one finally worked. In the process, the Hard Drive Cable got damaged somehow, and I needed to replace it too. Since then, everything has been working again (aside of the status indicator light that never worked since the HD cable was replaced but it doesn't really bother me)

Comment: That would be Normal, it is still removing the heat.

Comment: @Ruskes That's good to know in this case, thanks a lot !

Comment: @Ruskes Feel free to post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Ruskes If you have time, I also have another issue where the computer, if not already active, starts automatically when I plug in the charger. Feel free to have a look https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449084/macbook-pro-starts-automatically-when-charger-is-plugged-in

Comment: Please post your other questions separate, this site likes one question at the time to keep it clean.

Comment: But I will try to help with Wake. Click on Apple (top left) then on About This Mac, then on System Report, then find Power and click on it. Now go down the list and find the "Wake on AC Change: Yes/No ? Post the result in new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fan function is low level function.

It is simply controlled by thermal sensor.

The fan will keep running removing the heat if you close the lid till the thermal sensor tells it to stop.