# MacBook Pro starts automatically when charger is plugged in

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, battery, charging

MacBook Pro Unibody 15 inches mid 2012

When I plug the charger in and the computer isn't already turned on, it starts automatically. Of course, it also starts when I press the power button and the charger is not plugged in. And if I shut down the computer while the charger is plugged in, it does not restart the computer automatically which seems normal. It's only when I plug in the charger and the computer is not already turned on that the computer starts automatically.

---

A bit of context that may or may not be relevant:

The battery got swollen a year ago, and I needed to replace both the battery and the keyboard because some parts of the keyboard were damaged by the swollen battery and became unresponsive. The first replacement cable I got was defective, the second was accidentally damaged by me, and the third one finally worked. So I opened my computer at least 8 to 10 times to replace the keyboard until the last one finally worked. In the process, the Hard Drive Cable got damaged somehow, and I needed to replace it too. Since then, everything has been working again (aside of the keyboard backlight, and the status indicator light that never worked since the keyboard and the HD cable were replaced but it doesn't really bother me)

Comment: This is expected and normal behaviour. Whats the question?

Comment: @X_841 Really ? I don't remember that it started automatically before. Does your computer always start when you plug in the charger ? Is there a way to change it so it only starts when pushing the power button ?

Comment: I think all newer models definitely do this (including my 2017 MBP); not sure if yours maybe started this due to a software update? You should be able to turn it off though by pasting "sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00" in your terminal.

Comment: @X_841 Ah okay, in this case that's good to know. I already thought I destroyed something in the hardware. Feel free to post your comment as an answer. I will accept and upvote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My MacBook Pro from 2017 and AFAIK all models after that behave exactly like that - it is the intended behaviour. It could be that older models and also older OSes do not start up when connecting power. However, IMO this does not indicate any malfunction.

You can turn this off by pasting the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo nvram AutoBoot=%00
```

To turn it back on type and hit enter:

```
sudo nvram AutoBoot=%03
```